# Markers on google maps not showing, only after I made Hot restart on Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm stuck here, I have this code. But my markers are not showing up! in the map. Only when I made hot restart.
Im using RepaintBoundary to get the image that i want in my markers

```
 Widget _buildMarkerIcon() {

    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: _markerIconKey,
      child: Material(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('imagenes/Junior_logo.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

My buid method is this one:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Opacity(
              opacity: _opacity_num,
                child: _buildMarkerIcon()),
            Opacity(
              opacity: 1,
                child: _buildBody()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map),
        onPressed: _centerView,
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class _RegistroCuatroPageState extends State<RegistroCuatroPage> with AfterLayoutMixin<RegistroCuatroPage>{
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  final _text = TextEditingController();


  BitmapDescriptor icon;
  double _opacity_num = 1;
  Set<Marker> _markers = Set();
  GlobalKey _markerIconKey;
  Set<String> renderedMarkers = Set();


  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    // Calling the same function "after layout" to resolve the issue.
    //_addMarker();
    //_asyncMethod();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _markerIconKey = GlobalKey();
    setState(() {
    });
    super.initState();
  }
 
  void _addMarker() async {

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async
        {
          var markerBytes = await _getMarkerIconBytes(_markerIconKey);

          _markers.add(Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(IdTacosSauces),
              position: Constants.kTacosLocationSauces,
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerBytes)));

          setState(() {});
        }
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _getMarkerIconBytes(GlobalKey markerKey) async {
    if (markerKey.currentContext == null) return null;

    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        markerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();

    var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);

    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

My widget buid regarding the google maps is this one:

```
  Widget _buildBody() {
    return  GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition:
              CameraPosition(target: Constants.kTacosLocationSauces, zoom: 15),
          markers: _markers,

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
        _opacity_num = 0;
    });
    _mapController = controller;
    _addMarker();
    _centerView();
  }

  _centerView() async {
    await _mapController.getVisibleRegion();

    var cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);
    _mapController.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  }
}
```

I have tried also add the markers in the _onMapCreated callback but nothing.

Comment: Why did you wrap the code in `_addMarker` in a post frame callback? Try without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the problem was with RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage(). Theres is an issue open [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22308) explaining what is going on.

This solution works for me:

```
Future<Uint8List> _getMarkerIconBytes(GlobalKey markerKey) async {

var image;
if (markerKey.currentContext == null) return null;
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    markerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();


try {
  image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);
}catch(e){
  if (boundary.debugNeedsPaint) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20));
    return _getMarkerIconBytes(markerKey);
  }
}
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();}
```